# Give the upper limit of the difference between truncated power series and economized one (economized using Chebyshev polynomials).

Tags: numerical-methods, chebyshev-polynomials

The question is as follow:

(a) The first three Chebyshev polynomials are:
$$T_0=1$$
$$T_1 = x$$
$$T_2 = 2x^2-1$$
$$T_3 = 4x^3-3x$$
$$T_4 = 8x^4-8x^2+1$$

i) Economize the truncated power series:
$$p(x)=1+2x−x^3+3x^4$$

ii) Give the upper limit for the absolute value of the difference between the original truncated power series and the economized one.

My question relates to (ii). After economizing the given power series using Chebyshev polynomials, do I simply test values of $x$ in $[-1,1]$ using both the original and economized series and then determine the maximum error which would then be the upper limit/bound?

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I need to find the upper limit for the absolute value of the difference between the original truncated power series (above) and the economized one (the series is economized using Chebyshev polynomials).

Comment: What economized one?  $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $4$.  It can be written in terms of the Chebyshev polynomials $T_0(x), \ldots, T_4(x)$ if you wish.  This will be exact: the error is $0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael - I didn't include the economized series in my post as my question is more theoretical in nature. It is my understanding that to economize implies reducing the number of terms (degree of polynomial). So if the economized series contains fewer terms than the original one then there would be an error.

Comment: @CarlChristian - I have included the whole question in the original post. This is all the information given to me. I am not arguing that my information is sufficient. I just wished I knew what other information to give.

Comment: Forgive me, I now understand that "economized power series" is actual term. The key observation is that the decay rate of the Chebyshev coefficients is independent of the decay rate of the coefficients of the Taylor series. Write you polynomial as a weighted sum of Chebyshev polynomials. You will have exact equality. Disregard the terms one by one to gain different approximations. The error will be a polynomial of degree at most 4. You can find the range of the error function using standard techniques.

Comment: Let's see if I understand the problem correctly: you have to find $\sup_{x\in[-1,1]}|p(x)-q(x)|$, where $q(x)$ is the polynomial with degree $\leq 3$ which minimizes $\int_{-1}^{1}(p(x)-q(x))^2\,dx$. This is best tackled through Legendre polynomials, instead of Chebyshev polynomials. Or is $q(x)$ built through a Gaussian quadrature scheme? It is unclear to me what *economized* really means.